# No navigation bar or any navigation bar attributes are showing up in view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller that I want to have a navigation bar with a title and button to the right of the title. But for some reason the navigation bar is not showing up.

In the app delegate I added:

```
window?.rootViewController =
 UINavigationController(rootViewController: MessagesController())
 UITableViewCell.appearance().textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white;
 UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
 UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.15, blue:0.18, alpha:1.0)

 UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
```

In the viewDidLoad of the view controller I want to have the navigation bar this is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let dummyViewController = UIViewController()
    dummyViewController.view.backgroundColor = .white
    dummyViewController.navigationItem.title = "TEST"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

Why is there no navigation bar and why can't I add a title with buttons to it? Any help is welcome Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I once ran into the same issue with a dark `UINavigationBar`. Try to add this line in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

This solved the issue for me. Let me know if it helps.